# Abstract Base Classes: How do you define a copy constructor or assignment operator for a class that contains a pointer to a (abstract) base class?

Tags: c++, class, abstract-class, radix

I just encountered with question on [parashift.com](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/abcs)  regarding Abstract base classes in c++ .

Author has provided the solution in which  pure virtual member function `Clone()` has been created in Abstract Base Class.The purpose of this function is to create and return the address of clone object of ABC pointing to. Here I am bit confused that what is the use of creating this virtual function and overriding the Assignment operator and copy constructor if we achieve the same thing without doing this.

```
class Shape {

    public:
      // ...
      virtual Shape* clone() const = 0;   // The Virtual (Copy) Constructor
      // ...
};
```

Then we implement this `clone()` method in each derived class. Here is the code for derived class Circle:

```
class Circle : public Shape {

public:

  // ...
  virtual Circle* clone() const;
  // ...

};

Circle* Circle::clone() const
{
  return new Circle(*this);
}
```

Now suppose that each Fred object “has-a” Shape object. Naturally the Fred object doesn’t know whether the Shape is Circle or a Square or … Fred’s copy constructor and assignment operator will invoke Shape’s `clone()` method to copy the object:

```
class Fred {
public:
  // p must be a pointer returned by new; it must not be NULL
  Fred(Shape* p)
    : p_(p) { assert(p != NULL); }
 ~Fred()
    { delete p_; }
  Fred(const Fred& f)
    : p_(f.p_->clone()) { }
  Fred& operator= (const Fred& f)
    {
      if (this != &f) {              // Check for self-assignment
        Shape* p2 = f.p_->clone();   // Create the new one FIRST...
        delete p_;                   // ...THEN delete the old one
        p_ = p2;
      }
      return *this;
    }
  // ...
private:
  Shape* p_;
};
```

As I think we can achieve above behavior without overriding the Assignment operator or copy constructor. If we have two object `f1` (P_ pointing to Circle)  and `f2`(P_ pointing to Square) of type Fred. then

```
f1=f2;  // This line exhibits the same behavior what  above code is doing.
```

In the default case ,`P_`(Address of Square) of `f2` will get copied to `P_` to `f1`. now `f1` will point to Square. Only thing we need to take care is to delete the object of Circle otherwise it will be dangling state.

Why has the author mentioned the above technique to solve this problem?
Please Advise.

Comment: Why are you not using a copy constructor i.e. `Circle(const Circle& c)`

Comment: Fred holds a Shape pointer, so you would not be able to call the specific copy constructor.

Comment: Thanks. x squared. finally i understood

Comment: Great :) please accept the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that you can do

```
delete f1.p;
f1 = f2;
```

But this means that the user of the Fred class – who is not necessarily the author of it – is required to know that he has to call `delete f1.p` first. It might be obvious to you now, but other people would be very surprised that a simple assignment causes memory leaks. Also, if you return to your code after a long time, maybe you forget this little rule yourself and do the mistake.

Since you **always** have to delete the shape before assigning Fred, it is absolutely sensible to write this in the overriden equals operator. So the deletion happens automatically and the user does not need to worry about it.

**EDIT to answer question in comment**:

The `virtual Shape *clone()` function in the base class enforces every derived class to implement the clone() function. If you derive from Shape and forget to implement `clone()`, your code will not compile. This is good because the overriden assignment operator of Fred relies on it.

Comment: Yes. totally agreed. but still  did not understand that why he has created Clone virtual function to perform this action. Am i  missing any use case?

Comment: I edited my answer to explain this, too. I hope it clarifies the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you want to make a deep copy of your `Fred` object.  Since the destructor  does a `delete p_;`, if you had two `Fred` objects pointing at the same `Shape`, you would get a double free error.  The reason for the `clone()` interface is that `Fred` doesn't know what type of object `p_` points at, so it can't directly call the correct copy constructor.  Instead it relies on `Shape`'s subclasses to create copies of themselves and uses virtual method dispatch to create the right type of object.

Answer (score 0):

The example is not trying to make an assignment of f2 to f1, so the OP's belief that `f1 = f2;` exhibits the same behaviour is incorrect. The example is assigning a copy of f2 to f1, so the behaviour is closer to `f1 = new Whatever_f2_Is(*f2)`.

Since f2 is a pointer to a base class, there isn't enough information at this point to know which copy constructor to use (a slight lie, but the clone method is still easier to use). You cannot call new Shape() even if shape wasn't pure virtual and thus uninstantiatable because shape does not know the extra information of the sublclass. You would have a Shape, but lose all of the extra aspects of Circle-ness or Square-ness.

Fortunately while we know nothing about what is really at f2, the object at f2 still knows what it is, and we can delegate the creation of the copy to it. That's what the clone method does for you.

The alternative is to play is-a games or use a ID code and a factory.